# Thymeleaf do not attach all icons to template

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm facing a problem with **Thymeleaf** when I try to generate an email with icons on a template. I've followed the steps as the documentation suggests [See part 4.3](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html) but on the email only 2 of the 3 icons are shown.

First I load the icons:

```
private byte[] loadImage(String path, String extension) {
    byte[] image = new byte[0];

    try {
        URL file = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
        BufferedImage buffer = ImageIO.read(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(buffer, extension, outputStream);
        image = outputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        log.debug(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Then I add the icons to the `MimeMessageHelper`:

```
private void attachIcons(MimeMessageHelper message) {
    try {
        byte[] logoIconInBytes = loadImage(LOGO_ICON_PATH, "png");
        InputStreamSource logoImageSource = new ByteArrayResource(logoIconInBytes);
        message.addInline(LOGO_IMAGE_RESOURCE, logoImageSource, IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE);
        byte[] phoneIconInBytes = loadImage(PHONE_ICON_PATH, "png");
        InputStreamSource phoneImageSource = new ByteArrayResource(phoneIconInBytes);
        message.addInline(PHONE_IMAGE_RESOURCE, phoneImageSource, IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE);
        byte[] emailIconInBytes = loadImage(EMAIL_ICON_PATH, "png");
        InputStreamSource emailImageSource = new ByteArrayResource(emailIconInBytes);
        message.addInline(EMAIL_IMAGE_RESOURCE, emailImageSource, IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE);
    } catch (MessagingException exception) {
        log.debug(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Where:

```
private static final String LOGO_ICON_PATH = "data" + File.separator + "logo_example.png";
private static final String PHONE_ICON_PATH = "data" + File.separator + "phone.png";
private static final String EMAIL_ICON_PATH = "data" + File.separator + "email.png";
private static final String IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE = "image/png";
```

Then, I set the variables on the `context` before send the email:

```
......
context.setVariable(LOGO_IMAGE_RESOURCE, LOGO_IMAGE_RESOURCE);
context.setVariable(PHONE_IMAGE_RESOURCE, PHONE_IMAGE_RESOURCE);
context.setVariable(EMAIL_IMAGE_RESOURCE, EMAIL_IMAGE_RESOURCE);
String content = templateEngine.process(templateName, context);
......
```

And on the template I call the variables on their respective `<img>`:

```
....
<img class="resize" th:src="|cid:${logoIcon}|" alt="Test">
....
<td class="someCssClass"> <img th:src="|cid:${phoneIcon}|" alt="phone"> </td>
<td class="someCssClass"> <img th:src="|cid:${emailIcon}|" alt="email"> </td>
....
```

But the *email* icon it's not displayed, inspecting the *DOM* with Firefox Dev Tools I found this:

[image: Doom inspection]

You can see that the *Logo* and *Phone* icons are attached but the *Email* icon it's not attached.

I've changed of icon thinking that maybe the file was corrupted but nothing changed.

Where's the problem?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, by accident I've discovered the problem. I don't know if it's a bug or because I don't know how use the API but that's the weird thing that was happening:

When I added the icons:

```
byte[] logoIconInBytes = loadImage(LOGO_ICON_PATH, "png");
InputStreamSource logoImageSource = new ByteArrayResource(logoIconInBytes);
message.addInline(LOGO_IMAGE_RESOURCE, logoImageSource, IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE);
byte[] phoneIconInBytes = loadImage(PHONE_ICON_PATH, "png");
InputStreamSource phoneImageSource = new ByteArrayResource(phoneIconInBytes);
message.addInline(PHONE_IMAGE_RESOURCE, phoneImageSource, IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE);
byte[] emailIconInBytes = loadImage(EMAIL_ICON_PATH, "png");
InputStreamSource emailImageSource = new ByteArrayResource(emailIconInBytes);
message.addInline(EMAIL_IMAGE_RESOURCE, emailImageSource, IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

I removed the email code lines to write them again in case there was any mistake.

```
byte[] logoIconInBytes = loadImage(LOGO_ICON_PATH, "png");
InputStreamSource logoImageSource = new ByteArrayResource(logoIconInBytes);
message.addInline(LOGO_IMAGE_RESOURCE, logoImageSource, IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE);
byte[] phoneIconInBytes = loadImage(PHONE_ICON_PATH, "png");
InputStreamSource phoneImageSource = new ByteArrayResource(phoneIconInBytes);
message.addInline(PHONE_IMAGE_RESOURCE, phoneImageSource, IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

By accident I ran the application and generated and email and I noticed that the phone icon wasn't being displayed. I removed the phone icon and load only the logo, this time none icon was displayed on the email.

So, the solution it's add a dummy content after you load all the icons in order to be displayed.

```
byte[] logoIconInBytes = loadImage(LOGO_ICON_PATH, "png");
InputStreamSource logoImageSource = new ByteArrayResource(logoIconInBytes);
message.addInline(LOGO_IMAGE_RESOURCE, logoImageSource, IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE);
byte[] phoneIconInBytes = loadImage(PHONE_ICON_PATH, "png");
InputStreamSource phoneImageSource = new ByteArrayResource(phoneIconInBytes);
message.addInline(PHONE_IMAGE_RESOURCE, phoneImageSource, IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE);
byte[] emailIconInBytes = loadImage(EMAIL_ICON_PATH, "png");
InputStreamSource emailImageSource = new ByteArrayResource(emailIconInBytes);
message.addInline(EMAIL_IMAGE_RESOURCE, emailImageSource, IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE);
// Dummy content that won't be displayed to make all previous icons visible on the email
message.addInline("emptyIcon", new ByteArrayResource(new byte[0]), IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE);
```